# What is the exclamation mark in the "Racial and Specialization" category?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

What is the exclamation mark in the "racial and specialization" category? I know the question marks beside it are easy to fill in, but I'm at a loss about the exclamation mark.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?